# How can I get the name and package of all the classes loaded in the Java JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to get a full list of *all* the classes loaded in the JVM including the classes loaded by the bootloader, platformclassloader and custom class loaders.  Without using the Instrumentation API.

The methods exposed by the regular classLoaders return only the classes available in the package reference graph starting from the main function.   So I'm unable to get the list of classes loaded dynamically at runtime, and also can't get classes loaded by the bootloader and platformclassloader.

I'm aware of the Instrumentation API but can't control the command line arguments passed to the JVM so it's not an option for me.

I don't have any specific Java version constraints so I can take any solution on any 'live' version (lets say >=9)

Comment: you could try reflectively getting the `classes` field of all existing `ClassLoader` instances but that might not work in newer Java versions (and is inherently unsafe).

Comment: But the actual question is: Why do you need this? This question seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @dan1st i know this is a stupid answer but i have no reason to do this i just want to.
i tryed getting the classes from the field in ClassLoader but i need the instance of the classloader which is a problem with custom ClassLoader also not all ClassLoaders save the classes (the bootloader and some custom ClassLoader)

Comment: theoretically, you could do some sort of memory dump and parse it.

Comment: Executing `jcmd <pid> VM.class_hierarchy` (replacing <pid> with the process id of some java process) prints a hierarchical listing of the loaded classes to stdout.

Comment: i used jmap -dump

Comment: You would be able to get around the classloader instance issue with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76288918/21851535)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution specific to HotSpot JVM.
Works all JDK versions from 8 to 20.

The output is equivalent to what is printed by [`jmap -histo:all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490073/what-does-jmap-histo-pid-print-exactly), but instead of printing to stdout, the result is returned as a `String`.

```java
public static String getAllClassNames() throws JMException {
    return (String) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
            new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
            "gcClassHistogram",
            new Object[]{new String[]{"-all"}},
            new String[]{"[Ljava.lang.String;"});
}
```